# Warming up and "Greasing the groove" method

Tags: strength-training, injury, injury-prevention, warm-up, overtraining

"Greasing the groove" or GtG is a training method developed by Pavel Tsatsouline, and made popular through his book 1999 "Power to the People! : Russian Strength Training Secrets for Every American."

How do warming up fits into this system?

If you do several sets of pull-ups (or push-ups or whatever single exercise you'll try to optimize), are you supposed to do a proper warm up every time? Or it's OK to skip warm up, but then be extra slow?

From a purely pragmatic point of view, it seems extremely difficult to fit in warm-ups every time you decide to perform your push-ups.

Comment: I've always figured that if you're at the level of using GtG for an exercise, you're at the point where doing that exercise is itself no more than a warmup.

Comment: This is discussed here: https://www.strongfirst.com/community/threads/lifting-without-warmup.5031/

Answer (score 1):

One method is doing the movement with partial rom, for example, do a tiny rom pullup, then gradually increase the rom until you do 5 normal pullups

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a number of interpretations of the term *Greasing the Groove* floating around, but the term might be characterised by the fact that (1) lifting is sub-maximal, and (2) not performed to failure. So although performing a warm-up might optimise our strength for a lift, it is reasonable to suggest that for this method it is unnecessary, since we are not challenging our strength maximally.